# Outlook not showing in top of caller application

Tags: c#, outlook, late-binding

I'm using outlook to compose email using c#

The code i use is as follows:

```
object outlookApp = null;
object mailitem = null;
object att = null;

Type typeOutlook = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application");
Type typeMailItem = null;
Type typeAttachment = null;

outlookApp = Activator.CreateInstance(typeOutlook);

object[] parameters = new object[1] { 0 };
mailitem = typeOutlook.InvokeMember("CreateItem", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, outlookApp, parameters);
typeMailItem = mailitem.GetType();

att = typeMailItem.InvokeMember("Attachments", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, mailitem, null);
typeAttachment = att.GetType();

parameters = new object[1] { sSubject };
typeMailItem.InvokeMember("Subject", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, mailitem, parameters);

parameters = new object[1] { "someone@stackoverflow.com" };
typeMailItem.InvokeMember("To", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, mailitem, parameters);

parameters = new object[4] { @"c:\somefile.txt", 1, 1, "somefile.txt" };

try
{
    typeAttachment.InvokeMember("Add", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, att, parameters);
}
catch (Exception exAtt) { }

object inspector = typeMailItem.InvokeMember("GetInspector", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, mailitem, null);
Type typInspector = inspector.GetType();
//typInspector.InvokeMember("Activate", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, inspector, null);

parameters = new object[1] { true };
typInspector.InvokeMember("Display", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, inspector, parameters);

//parameters = new object[1] { true };
//typeMailItem.InvokeMember("Display", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, mailitem, parameters);
```

The problem is that, on some machines, the dialog does not show in front of my application. Any ideas on why? I can't seem to understand. As stated above, i tries using display from the mail item and Display from the inspector, but that doesn't solve the problem.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what dialog are you referring to ?

Comment: try mailItem.Display(true);

Comment: I'm referring to the compose email dialog. I've tried Display(true) - It's in the example, on the commented lines, but thanks anyway!

Comment: well, I had a similar module that I implemented last year.
Posting the code snippet below in my answer, that should help you out

Comment: hi MSantos, can you please confirm if the code snippet below or any other answer, helped you solve your question, if yes please consider clicking on the green tickbox to accept it

Answer (score 0):

Display the item modelessly (`MailItem.Display(false)`), then activate the `Inspector` object by calling `MaiLItem.GetInspector` / `Inspector.Activate`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stated in your comments that you have already tried Display(true) , thought I will post what we tried some time ago.

This is from one of the simple modules we had used for Outlook and I remember it worked well

Was tested on Win10 and Win7 with O365 / Outlook2016

> Be sure to add COM Reference in VS "Outlook Object 16" I believe its
>   called

---

```
           using System;
           using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
           using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

           public Class Outlook
           {
               public void SendMail()
               {
                    Outlook.Application outlookObj = null;

                    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
                    Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                    oMailItem.To = "xyz@gmail.com";
                    oMailItem.Subject = $"Primary user confirmed, survey sent";
                    oMailItem.Body = $"Please find below {userEmail.Text}";
                    oMailItem.Display(true);

                    oMailItem.Send();

                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oApp);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oMailItem);

                }

           }
```